# Deprecated warning only in some php5 environments?

Tags: php, deprecated, php4

We're moving from php4 to php5, and we get this warning on one of our developers machines, but not in our php5 test setup:

Deprecated: Call-time pass-by-reference has been deprecated in C:\Workspace\Prelive\www\includes\filename etc..

The code seems to be the same in both environments, and the php.ini on the test environment has this setup for errors:

error_reporting =  E_STRICT | E_ALL

We could ofcourse just fix the code so the warning will go away, but my main concern is why the test environment is not complaining about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a php.ini directive called [`allow_call_time_pass_reference`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.allow-call-time-pass-reference), which may be off in the environment which does not complain about it.

Comment: Thanks, this was it. Some background, we started with an almost clean php.ini for the test environment, which makes it default to allow_call_time_pass_reference being on. This devel machine has the setting turned off, which is apparently the default on the wamp environment the particular devel is using

Answer (score 1):

You've probably checked this already, but is

```
display_errors = On
```

set in both ini files?